# Adjusting the size of several pie charts in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(Subjects = c("Literature", "Literature", "Geography", "Geography", "Arts", "Arts", 
                              "English", "English", "Math", "Math", "History", "History", 
                              "Biology", "Biology", "French", "French"),
                 Sex = rep(c("Girls", "Boys"), 2),
                 N = c(15, 20, 30, 22, 77, 40, 14, 17, 
                       80, 78, 52, 65, 32, 56, 89, 41)) |>
  group_by(Subjects) |>
  mutate(pct = proportions(N) * 100) |>
  mutate_at(vars(pct), list(~ round(., 1))) |>
  ungroup()

df |>
  ggplot(aes(x = "", y = pct, fill = Sex)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1, color = "white", na.rm = TRUE) +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  facet_wrap(~ Subjects,
             ncol = 4,
             strip.position = "bottom") +
  geom_text(aes(y = pct, label = paste0(pct, "%")), size = 5, 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 12)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.0),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.spacing.y = unit(0.0, 'cm'),
        legend.box.spacing = unit(-2, "pt")) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(byrow = TRUE)) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2")
```

I need to create a plot scaling each pie chart from largest (Math = 158 students) to smallest (English = 31). I appreciate the help.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Work out the size of each group, and make your bars the same width as the square root of this number. Instead of making the x axis value a nameless string, make it half the value of this square root so that its 'left' edge in Cartesian co-ordinates is always at zero:

```r
df |>
  mutate(size = sum(N), .by = Subjects) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = sqrt(size)/2, y = pct, fill = Sex)) +
  geom_col(aes(width = sqrt(size)), color = "white", 
           na.rm = TRUE) +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  facet_wrap(~ Subjects,
             ncol = 4,
             strip.position = "bottom") +
  geom_text(aes(y = pct, label = paste0(pct, "%")), size = 5, 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 12)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.0),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.spacing.y = unit(0.0, 'cm'),
        legend.box.spacing = unit(-2, "pt")) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(byrow = TRUE)) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2")
```

[image]

It may help to visualize how this works by switching to Cartesian co-ordinates:

```r
df |>
  mutate(size = sum(N), .by = Subjects) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = sqrt(size)/2, y = pct, fill = Sex)) +
  geom_col(aes(width = sqrt(size)), color = "white", 
           na.rm = TRUE) +
  facet_wrap(~ Subjects,
             ncol = 4,
             strip.position = "bottom") +
  geom_text(aes(y = pct, label = paste0(pct, "%")), size = 4, 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2")
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Thanks @Allan Camero.